# minimal rsync installation on windows xp?

Tags: rsync

I want to install rsync on windows xp.

I have searched the web, but most of the solutions suggest using cygwin, but is there any other way to do this?

I don't want to install cygwin because it takes lot of space. Moreover, I need to make it communicate with a rsync daemon on Linux, therefore alternatives to rsync on windows won't help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[First hit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rsyncwin32/) on Google for "rsync win32".

Comment: That project is in aplha. Still, 5 years after this answer has been posted.